# Slow down scroll to top event by jQuery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like my page to go to the top when certain anchor is clicked.

Here is how I tried to do it but it's not working, it's scrolling super fast.

```
 $('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
        $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
        },
        50);
});
```

I want to slow it down.

Comment: You can solve it using CSS, try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729464/9334155)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
$('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});
```

Perhaps?

Comment: Any idea why `$('html, body')` is required? I tried it with `$(window)`, but it didn’t seem to have any effect, which I kind of expected it to seeing as (if I remember correctly) it’s the window object that keeps track of the scroll position?

Comment: window is veiwport but you need to animate the document html, also you don't need body

  $("html").animate({scrollTop: $("#whatever_id_you_want_to_go_to").offset().top}, 1200);

Comment: I think you do need `body` as `html` won't work in all browsers.

Comment: so you need both body and html to support all browsers?

Comment: How about adding [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent flashing of page before scrolling to top?

Comment: body is used by webkit browsers, html is used by firefox.

Comment: As of now Chrome and Safari seem to work fine with just html.

Comment: @dmnd Are you sure? It's not working for me in Chrome 50.0.2661.94. I'm testing with this: https://jsfiddle.net/8uswq8u3/

Comment: @AdamTaylor this answer is more than 6 years old, probably some things have changed

Comment: @ant I wasn't responding to the answer; I was responding to a comment that was made less than two years ago.

Comment: Better to be safe then sorry and use html & body, using both shouldn't cause any hiccups.

Comment: Just FYI: These days it would be likely best if you did `$(document.scrollingElement)`, because there is such a prop these days.

Answer (score 10):

When you pass 50 as the second parameter to animate, that is 50 milliseconds. See the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation. Either pass a larger number, or as c0mrade suggested, simply pass 'slow' .

Answer (score 0):

you can set the time for scroll top

```
$('a[href=#top]').click(function(){
 $('body').animate({
     scrollTop: 0},4000);});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href=\\#top]').click(function(){
  $('body').animate(
    {
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 
    2000
  );
});
```

The # should be escaped \\#.