# jQuery .animate({scrollTop: ... }) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have single .html file

I have `<ul>` menu and `<li>`'s have data-id attributes. I have several content items, which has same id's as menu `<li>`'s `data-id`'s. By default most of content items are `display:none;` first page content is `display:block;`

```
<ul>
    <li class="menuLink" id="onepage" data-id="one"></li>
    <li class="menuLink" id="twopage" data-id="two"></li>
    <li class="menuLink" id="threepage" data-id="three"></li>
    <li class="menuLink" id="fourpage" data-id="four"></li>
</ul>
<div class="content">
    <div id="one" class="page">...</div>
    <div id="two" class="page">...</div>
    <div id="three" class="page">...</div>
    <div id="four" class="page">...</div>
</div>
```

This script should appear and disappear content items by clicking on menu items. This works very well.

```
$('li.menuLink').click(function () {
    var elem = $(this);
    if (elem.hasClass('active')) {
    } else {
        $('li.active').removeClass('active');
        elem.addClass('active');
        $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).prependTo($('.content'));
        var existing = $('.page:visible');
        (existing) ? existing.fadeOut(1) : '';
        $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).delay(10).fadeIn(400);

        if (($('.body-wrapper').width()) <= 700) {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).offset().top}, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

If `.body-wrapper` width is less then 700 (mobile device), this script should also scroll down to content, but this function isn't working at all. Once you refresh page and click FIRST menu element, it works once. after that... nothing.

```
if (($('.body-wrapper').width()) <= 700) {
            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).offset().top}, 500);
        }
```

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/wBUS7/2/

Comment: Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034659/is-it-possible-to-animate-scrolltop-with-jquery. Might help you.

Comment: @putvande this is what already use OP, or i missing something?!

Comment: Is `$('.body-wrapper').width()` returning expected result?

Comment: yes, `$('.body-wrapper').width()` is working

Comment: and here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wBUS7/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `each()` function.
Like

```
$('li.menuLink').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (elem.hasClass('active')) {
        } else {
            $('li.active').removeClass('active');
            elem.addClass('active');
            $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).prependTo($('.content'));
            var existing = $('.page:visible');
            (existing) ? existing.fadeOut(1) : '';
            $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).fadeIn(400);

            if (($('.body-wrapper').width()) <= 700) {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).offset().top}, 500);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You said it was working for the first time. and after that nothing happens. So I have added each() function which will work for each li in your list.

Comment: Yes, i understand, what `each()` does, but see yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/wBUS7/3/
It's not working. Make the result window width less then 700px and click run. After that only clicking 'FIRST' works and only once.

Comment: found the solution. just remove dealay(10) from line $('#' + elem.attr('data-id')).delay(10).fadeIn(400);