# Smooth scroll css code from <a href""> to div tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div style="border-radius: 10px; border: 2px solid #a1a1a1; padding: 10px 20px; width:      94%;">
<ul>
<li>Course details in different countries
<ul>
<li><a href="#bdpindia">India</a></li>
<li><a href="#bdpaus">Australia</a></li>
<li><a href="#bdpuk">United Kingdom</a></li>
<li><a href="#bdpch">China</a></li>
<li><a href="#bdpeng">England</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I wrote this code to jump to that particular div tags according to their # id's in the href. I wanted to jump to the div with smooth scrolling effect. Any CSS implementation needed?

Comment: to scroll you may want to consider jQuery

Answer (score 1):

try this [**jQuery.ScrollTo**](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)

```
$.scrollTo('a[href=bdpaus]');
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox and Chrome, you can use the `scroll-behavior: smooth` CSS; this is [not yet supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior) in other browsers, but [polyfills](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) do exist.

```css
* {line-height: 3em}
body {scroll-behavior: smooth}
```

```html
<a href="#bottom">Click</a>
<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>a<br>b<br>c<br>
<div id="bottom">end of page</div>
```

You could also use jQuery to [animate the page's `scrollTop`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034659/is-it-possible-to-animate-scrolltop-with-jquery), but unless you are already using jQuery for other purposes I wouldn't think it worth including the entire library for just one cosmetic function.