# How to scroll a webpage vertically in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, vertical-scrolling

I want to write an Jquery or JS script to scroll down a given page if it has the vertical scrollbar. This is to automate the web page navigation using the mouse wheel, so I should be able to animate it with time.

I was reading the web but seems that to do something like this you need to know an element name. Is it possible without knowing any element name? Something like `$(document).scrollDown(speed)`?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034659/is-it-possible-to-animate-scrolltop-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You could animate `scrollTop` property of  `html` and `body` elements, like this:

```
 $(window).load(function() {
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: yPosition }, 1000);
 });
```

In this snippet, `yPosition` represents the height you want to reach, and `1000` controls the speed.

Answer (score 1):

To detect if the page has a vertical scroll bar you could do:

```
if((document).height() > (window).height())
{
   $('html').animate({scrollTop : ((document).height()},'slow');
}
```