# Can I use scrollTop without writing a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some trouble with my jQuery and was looking for some solutions to add something to my already existing `slideDown` function.

What looked very interesting to me is this question/answer from 2010 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034659/is-it-possible-to-animate-scrollop-with-jquery](http://Stackoverflow.com)

The difference to that question is that I'm looking for a solution to `scrollTop` each time to a different `<a> anchor`.

In my example below, the `<a href"#">` is suppose to move to the top.

Is that possible?

HTML

```
<div class="next_btn" id="next_btn_show_step_3">
    <a href="#"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
</div>
<article class="order_form_step_3" id="banner_step_3">
</article>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#banner_step_3").hide();

  $("#next_btn_show_step_3").click(function(e){
    $("#banner_step_3").slideDown(500);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily adapt that answer like this:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: Math.floor($('#yourElement').offset().top) + "px" });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just tried it and it works great! +1 since I struggling with this for almost 2 days now...

Comment: This doesn't explain how to add to the existing `slideDown` function to scroll to a different `anchor` when each is clicked like OPs question asked, only how to scroll to one element by `id`.

Answer (score 0):

**jquery**

```
$('.next_btn a').on('click', function(e) {//on link click
    var th = $(this);//get element
    th.parent().next('article').slideDown(500);//slide down
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: th.offset().top }, 500);//scrollto link
    e.preventDefault();//prevent default
});
```