# Trying to replicate scroll-down button hover effect

Tags: jquery, css

Does anyone know how to add a hovering effect to a scroll down button the same as this site -  http://www.rex-kralj.com/home? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show your code where you are facing problem. We can't just tell you how to make it.

Comment: I didnt see any scroll down button :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it easy, you have some jQuery plugins like [PageScroller](http://pagescroller.com/) or [fullPage](http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/). There are more, just look for "jquery scroll page" at google and you'll find lots.

Answer (score 0):

A simple jQuery code can do what you want :

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(window).height()+"px"});
})
```

`$(window).height()` means the height of your screen, but you can put the value you want. Have a look to this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034659/is-it-possible-to-animate-scrolltop-with-jquery).

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but I meant how to make the button hover up and down continuously.