# Smooth scroll with slide() in jQuery, doesn't scroll smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a simple html file, with anchor links that can be clicked to scroll smoothly to their respective part of the page ( tags). The problem is that the scroll is not smooth at all!
I watched a tutorial on youtube and the code used in there was (here's the code I adapted to fit on my project, but the way is the same):

```
function goto(numsection){
        var section = $('#section'+numsection);
        var offset = section.offset().top;
        $(document).scrollTop(offset);
        $(section).slide('slow');
}
```

When I click an anchor, the page scrolls down to the respective section, but the transition is immediate. In JavaScript console there's this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I don't understand, in the tutorial worked perfectly.

PS: I want to use `slide()` function if possible, not `slideToggle()` or similar.

Comment: You're not animating the scroll.  Look at this SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element

Comment: But in the video it worked... it didn't use animate(), just slide().

Comment: I can't comment on a video that I can't see.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnlDEoWxHfc min 11:00

Comment: Google animate scrollTop: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034659/is-it-possible-to-animate-scrolltop-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you haven't watched that video.
In said video, that code you posted never achieves smooth scrolling, just sudden jumps.
I don't know why would you just want to use `slide()` and nothing but. I'm not familiar with `slide()`, I know `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`, but those serve other purposes.

However, here is the way I like to handle scrolling (or check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/porjolovsky/7HK8Q/embedded/result/)):

```
$(".link").on('click', function(e)
{        
    $(".link").each(function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    });

    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var scrollSpeed = 2000;
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() - 50;
    var id = $(this).attr('data-scroll-to');

    var goTo =  $('#s'+ id).offset().top;

    e.preventDefault();

    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: goTo }, scrollSpeed);

});
```

Comment: ..............
I watched that video at least 4 times! And with the code I wrote up, it makes a smooth scroll.

Maybe the problem is related to different jQuery versions... I don't know.

Comment: I thought jQuery versions could be the problem. I still don't see what is that you refer to as "smooth scroll". Exact time in video could help.

Comment: Around 11:00. The smooth scroll doesn't appear to be very smooth because of the video, but it's smooth scroll (slide( ) function took 'slow' as a param = slide('slow')).

Comment: The thing is the smooth scroll doesn't even appear to be scroll, and it's quickly replaced by the never-failing fadeIn. Try `animate()`, as suggested in my answer and in the comments above, or explain which is the result you are looking for that can't be achieved by use of this method.

Comment: The result I'm looking for is the same I get with animate(), but with the usage of slide() instead. Well, I will use animate()... thanks.

Comment: _Why_ are you trying to use `slide()`? If the result is the same, what am I missing? Is there logic behind your desire to use `slide()`, or is it just a whim?

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn jQuery and slide() it seemed easier to me to remember and to use. Also, I wanted to know why didn't work. But ok, animate() is a good solution too.

Comment: The thing is, `slide()` doesn't seem to be a jQuery function at all.

Comment: Maybe is totally deprecated. :/