# My Javascript only works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have javascript in a Rails project that only runs in Chrome.  I've tested it in Firefox and IE and I get nothing.  Am I overlooking something simple?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#edit").on("click", function() {
    $("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY+130}, 1000);
    return false;
}),
$("#edit-on-two").on("click", function() {
    $("body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY+130}, 1000);
    return false;
});
})
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add "html" as an element in the `animate()` call, like this:

```
$("html, body").animate({"scrollTop": window.scrollY+130}, 1000);
```

There are issues with Webkit/Firefox and whether they can animate "html" or "body".

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4034659/is-it-possible-to-animate-scrolltop-with-jquery/#4034674) for more information on html vs. body