# jQuery animate scrollTop not working in IE 7

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

The following works in Chrome / FF etc...

```
$('body').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 0);
```

However, in IE 7, it doesn't do anything.
Is there an alternative?

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince jQuery animate absolutely works on scrollTop. I've used it in production many times, cross browser.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123690/jquery-animate-scroll-top-top-slow

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**EDIT** As pointed out by many, it is better to use:

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 0);
```

Comment: I don't think this works in all browsers.  `'body, html'` is a better selector (see other answer).

Comment: This doesnt work well in all browsers. Rather use the other answer.

Answer (score 17):

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

in IE8， i use `$(document).scrollTop()` to get the scrollTop property, `$('body').scrollTop()` or `$('html').scrollTop()` will always return 0.

Maybe you can use

```
$(document).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 0);
```

to make it works on all browser.

Answer (score 2):

Set:

```
# FF、IE8        
document.documentElement.scrollTop = 100;

# chrome
document.body.scrollTop = 100;
```

Get:

```
scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop;
```