# vertical document scroll position in JavaScript that is cross-browser compatible up to IE 8

Tags: javascript, scroll-position

I am wanting the scroll position of the document element in JavaScript, since I cannot use jQuery.

**Question**: What would be the JavaScript code for getting the document's vertical scroll position?  I need to make it compatible as far back as IE 8 and all modern browsers.

**UPDATE 1**: 
I reviewed the 2 answers given as duplicates of this. The first one does address my problem though its not focusing on a cross-browser solution, but the second one is way off what I need. I need the vertical scroll position of document and not scrolling to the top of document. The second post talks about using a link or going step by step to top of document, which does not address my question.

**UPDATE 2**:
Based on the answer provided by minitech, I came up with following functions to determine scroll positions that works across all modern browsers as well as upto IE 8. I tested this and it worked in Chrome, FireFox, Opera, Edge , IE 8, IE 9, IE 10 and IE 11.

```
function getScrollY() {
        return  window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;
}

function getScrollX() {
    return window.scrollX || window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft;
}
```

Comment: I believe is is just `document.scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: I need the scrollPosition only, but I do not want to scroll to top. I think what you suggested will scroll the document to top. Right?

Comment: You can see the answer in the following SO thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661896/are-there-alternatives-to-jquery-scrolltop

Comment: is `window.scrollY` cross-browser?

Comment: @Sunil Yes, sorry. It would be `var scrollPosition = document.scrollTop;`. I read it too fast. :)

Comment: @Sunil I think so. It's a basic.

Comment: @imtheman, I tried your approach, but it gives `undefined`, but the jQuery version gives a value of 828. So it seems, scrollTop cannot be used.

Comment: @akinuri, Even using document.scrollY gives 0 when the jQuery version gives 828. So it doesn't seem right.

Comment: It seems IE8 doesn't support `scrollY` [IE8 alternative to window.scrollY?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618785/ie8-alternative-to-window-scrolly).

Comment: `document` isn't an element, so `document.scrollTop` will never work. However, as mentioned in both flagged duplicates, `document.body.scrollTop` will.

Comment: @akinuri, I am using Google Chrome and it doesn't work in Chrome also, since I just tested before posting the comment.

Comment: It's not `document.scrollY`. Try `window.scrollY`.

Comment: @akinuri, Sorry my mistake. Yes, I just checked and it gives 828 which is same as the jQuery version. Thanks,

Comment: Sorry? If you really `... am not interested in scrolling to top` then why did you ask `$(document).scrollTop() equivalent in JavaScript`? At 2.5k rep you should know how to state your question more clearly by now.

Comment: @JK, I asked `What would be the JavaScript code for getting the document's scroll position?`. But if you think otherwise then that's ok by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use the source:](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/c9cf250daafe806818da1dd207a88a8e94a4ad16/src/offset.js#L193)

```
var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;
```

Compatibility notes:

- `document.body.scrollTop` doesn’t work (is always 0) in Firefox; it’s `document.documentElement.scrollTop` if you want to use a `scrollTop` at all. Conversely, `document.documentElement.scrollTop` is always 0 in Chrome (well, Blink and WebKit).
- `window.scrollY` doesn’t exist in IE 8 and earlier.

So, for old IE compatibility, use:

```
var scrollPosition =
    'pageYOffset' in window ?
        window.pageYOffset :
        document.body.scrollTop;
```

Comment: Wow. this gives the exact value as the jQuery scrollTop. Will this work in all browsers?

Comment: @Sunil: This will work in browsers jQuery 2.x supports, so IE 9 and later. If you need earlier versions, you can also check the source for jQuery 1.x (falls back on `document.body.scrollTop`, I believe).

Comment: So I can just use `document.body.scrollTop`. Right? I just checked it also gives the same value as jQuery scrollTop in Chrome.

Comment: @Sunil: No, that doesn’t work in Firefox. Try `var scollPosition = 'pageYOffset' in window ? window.pageYOffset : document.body.scrollTop;` if you need IE 8 and earlier compatibility.

Comment: it's `document.documentElement.scrollTop` in std mode, `document.body.scrollTop` only works in quirksmode for IE and FF (it's a doctype thing, not an old IE thing). since the other will be a zero when inactive a "||" can seperate the two to read the scroll pos.

Comment: @minitech,  Ok. Great. I appreciate your excellent answer on this. To the point and simple.