# IE ScrollTop property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following code in order to ease a scroll to the top of a page:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#top').on("click",function(){
        $("body").stop().animate({scrollTop: 0},"slow");
    });
})
```

It works perfectly fine on chrome, doesn't work on IE, in IE, the scrollbar doesn't even move. Nothing happens.

Any suggestions how to deal with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Googling?

```
$('body, html').animate({scrollTop : 0}, 0);
```

[jQuery animate scrollTop not working in IE 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519286/jquery-animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-ie-7)

Comment: Well, I didn't really know what to google. BTW, I didn't think it was something to do with the selector since it did work a week ago, and now it doesn't. But hey, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

For IE, you may need to add **html** to your selector for the animation, as IE does not seem to recognize the animation on the body element.

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#top').on("click",function(){
        $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: 0},"slow");
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks sir! Good night ^_^!