# scroll back to top animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

Afternoon

Problem: Instead of scrolling to the top with animation my "back to the top" button (down-right corner after scrolling down) jumps right to the top.

Example can be found on http://www.pixsters.be

My html:

```
<a href="#top" id="homebacktothetop"><span>backtothetop</span></a>
```

My js (jquery):

```
            // scroll to 0 when clicked
            $('#homebacktothetop').click(function () {
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: dont know. But the click event handler has a `preventDefault` method you can use instead of `return false;` if you want to prevent the link doing it's normal job. `.click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `'body,html'` to `window`

```
$('#homebacktothetop').click(function (e) {
    $(window).animate({
         scrollTop: 0
     }, 800);
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

typo: you try to call

```
function gotoByScroll(id)
{
     $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
}
```

with

```
$("#homebacktothetop").click(function(){goToByScroll("#container");});
```

Which gives you a Uncaught ReferenceError: goToByScroll is not defined  in the console, 
javascript is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#GoToTop").click(function()
              {
                 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
                return false;
              });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete shot in the dark, but have you tried removing the return statement? I was looking at a similar post, [jquery animate, scroll top top slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123690/jquery-animate-scroll-top-top-slow), and they got the same script to work, but they have no return statement.

On a completely different topic, you're getting these Javascript errors in your page:
[image]
[image]

Might wanna look into that, it seems like therein lies your problem.
Good luck!

Comment: Or I guess changing to Window like Kei said will do it xD

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you got your code from [Web Designer Wall](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top).  I noticed in your code that on line 32 you overwrite the click event for #homebacktothetop with a new function.