# page scroll down automatically

Tags: c#

Is there any jquery, or any feature in c#,

I have done a lot Google , but not able to find the solutions

I want the page to be scroll down slowly ( with some time interval) automatically

for example, there is a news webpage, some one is reading article, so slowly slowly page should be scroll down so user don't need to scroll it manually

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123690/slow-down-scroll-to-top-event-by-jquery-animate?

Comment: downvoters are welcome to there opinion, I have read "carefully" and your question still doesn't show any of your own effort (I didnt downvote)

Comment: @Sayse i have mention there that i did google , but dint find any thing related to that, its not always happen that you searched and you get the result

Comment: [this](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html), I also found Keyboards answer, the [fourth entry on this search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=automatic+scroll+webpage&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=Fd5&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=automatic+scroll+webpage+c%23&oq=automatic+scroll+webpage+c%23&gs_l=serp.3..33i29i30l4.23986.24219.0.24323.3.3.0.0.0.0.81.216.3.3.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.Pa1PPxiqYZc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZG4&fp=f59eaea25f195acf&biw=1348&bih=849)

Comment: @Sayse i clicked the same link you given "fourth entry on this search" but up to 10th page i dint find the link "this" ,  yes this really very bad, to expect that whatever you get the result on google other person also can get,  i am giving snapshot of two first page, http://postimg.org/image/r2h6xeaa7/ and http://postimg.org/image/53mwwdl17/ check this

Comment: but any way thanks i got the link from u guys

Comment: no worries, (FYI its fourth link in your first image)

Comment: really, it seems i have got some problem in my eyes, here i am able to see c#-corner link, will have to go to the doctor, thanks any ways

Answer (score 1):

First result I googled: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html

Here is the scroll function they suggest calling on page load:

```
function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',100); // scrolls every 100 milliseconds
}
```

I think it would be better to place an fixed position invisible div over say the bottom 20% of the page, and if the user moves a mouse there to start scrolling, because I find pages that try and do things automatically (e.g. playing music/video on sites that are not focused on those media) quite irritating personally.

Answer (score 1):

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("javascript:var s = function() { window.scrollBy(0,10); setTimeout(s, 100); }; s();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 200
        }, 4000);
    });
</script>
```