# How can I add a scroll speed to my script window.scroll?

Tags: javascript, html

I am really new and my last question wasn't correct so here I go again. I was able to get the scroll to work to go to the top and bottom but right now it just snaps there and back. I want to give it a movement. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
document.getElementById('sur2').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('pt1').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('pt2').style.display='none';
    window.scroll(0,0); 


}


document.getElementById('sur1').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById('pt1').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('pt2').style.display='block';
    window.scroll(0,5000);

}
```

Comment: there are a lot of "smooth scroll" plugins and stand-alone routines out there, just search for one and ask if you get stuck implementing it.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19302053/i-am-trying-to-make-my-page-scroll-slower-when-you-press-a-button-using-jquery/19302204#19302204

Comment: @Pricey - the question you linked is about JQuery, while this one is about pure js.

Comment: @Dementic ok yes but it was the same person with the same code asking to do the same thing with a removed tag. This doesn't need 2 questions just specify js or jquery or ask for "with and without jQuery" examples. Applying a speed to a cross browser scroll just with javascript is a bit more advanced when the OP states they are new to jQuery when it wasn't jQuery to begin with. I have also added an answer for what they are doing to that other question using jQuery, so maybe someone won't waste their time doing the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying and re-inventing the wheel,
You could use a ready made script and modify it to your likings.
a pretty nice script i know in plain javascript would be http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/

if you need help implementing it, or have problems modifying it, ask a question.