# Scrolling webview credit text in android

Tags: android, animation, webview

I need to make a credits screen in my application. It would be vertically scrolling lines. It is html page with images so I can only use webview. Scrolling is to be performed automatically and no user interaction is allowed. Just like movie/serials credits that goes from bottom to top. I have html page added in assets folder.

How to implement this animation?

Comment: Try http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_marquees.htm

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a webview, you can actually use jQuery to accomplish this.

```
$('a[href=#bottom]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});
```

[Slow down scroll to top event by jQuery animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123690/slow-down-scroll-to-top-event-by-jquery-animate)

Or you could use a handler

```
private Runnable mScrollDown = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_url);
        webview.scrollBy(0, scrollSpeed);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 200);
    }
};
```