# auto-scrolling text view in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

I want to add a scrolling `textView` in my android app, like the one we see in the ending of movies, it should scroll automatically till the end of the content. Scrolling is to be performed automatically without any user interaction.

How could I achieve in animating it like that?
Would it require a `scrollView` or a certain android library?

I've visited articles on Stack like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472362/android-automatic-horizontally-scrolling-textview), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737994/scrolling-webview-credit-text-in-android/23747066#23747066) but none solve my query

Answer (score 0):

Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
repositories {
            
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.BosnianDev:ScrollingTextView:1.0'
}
```

**Usage**

```
<com.github.BosnianDev.ScrollingTextView
      android:id="@+id/ScrollTextView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

For more details [visit here](https://github.com/BosnianDev/ScrollingTextView)